# map comparator operator overloading

Tags: c++, dictionary, comparator, functor

I am trying to use the Comparator for map's key comparison.

```
std::map<SomePointer,SomeValue, SomeComparator> testMap;

class SomeComparator
{
   SomeComparator( ){ }

   bool operator()( const SomePointer& sp1, const SomePointer& sp2) const
   {
      return sp1 == sp2;
   }
}
```

My question is whether I need to overload the operator( ) or something else for allowing the map::find to use the appropriate comparator for comparing two pointers and retrieve the matching one.

Comment: The comparator should return true if the first argument is < than the second, not ==. Other than that, nope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For map you need to provide a `<` type of comparison -- a "strict weak ordering", to be specific. It deduces equality when A is not less than B and B is not less than A.

But, to answer the question you actually asked: if you're providing a comparator functor as above, you overload `operator()` for that functor. Otherwise, you can overload `operator<` for your key type.